# Delphi 7 Exe is not working in Non-delphi machine

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Recently i got a chance to work on delphi 7. I just created a sample application which display a welcome message and that exe is working fine on Delphi machine. if i moved that exe to non-delphi machine(where delphi is not installed), it is throwing error as **"The program can't start beause rtl70.bpl is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem"**.

if i follow the same process with Delphi 5, it is working fine.

Comment: Either deploy your application with runtime libraries (those rtl*.bpl files), or go to project options and uncheck there the option *Build with runtime packages* in the *Packages* tab.

Comment: Hi Lama, thanks for your quick replay.
i am building the exe by unchecking the option "Build with run time packages". still it is asking for bpl's.

Comment: Have you re-build your application (menu *Project | Build YourProject*), not just re-compiled ? It's not enough to re-compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have built the program to rely on runtime packages. That means that each machine that needs to run the program needs to have the runtime packages available.

There are two solutions:

1. Distribute the runtime packages that you use alongside the executable.
2. Disable runtime packages and so build an executable that contains the runtime.

The runtime packages options are determined by settings specified in the project options.

Unless you have some compelling reason to use runtime packages, the second option is much simpler because it allows the executable file to stand alone, with no external dependencies.

Comment: Hi David, thank for your quick replay.
i am building the exe with "Build with run time packages" option unchecked in project->options->packages.
is that you are mentioned in second point?

Comment: I have followed second step, still it is asking for bpl files

Comment: The message indicates that you are building with runtime packages.